# Visual Studio 2010 drop down menus don't work

Tags: visual-studio

I've looked for an answer to this everywhere. It's not a problem with the applications I'm writing, it's a problem with the IDE itself. Whenever I try to access the dropdown menus in Visual studio like File, Edit, etc... I can't see them. I'd post a picture but new users can't. The menus will come up with some pixelated garbage that is useless.

I'm running VS2010 on a Dell Vostro 1000 running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit, 4GB RAM. I don't know if this is a hardware issue and I've tried re-installing several times. Same result every time.

Comment: Very strange.  Can you post a picture on an external site and link it?  I'm curious what this looks like.  Has this happened in any other applications?  Does it happen for other users on the same system?  Does i happen over, say, remote desktop?  Just trying to narrow down a pattern.

Comment: Try updating your video card driver. This often helped my end users big time when we tried fixing any seemingly unrelated graphical bugs.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/ivKBi) maybe this will help. I've tried updating video card driver but the chip I have technically doesn't have a driver for windows 7.

Comment: @user Well, if you're using graphics hardware with Windows 7 that isn't supported by Windows 7, that sure sounds like it could be the problem.  Did it work properly at any point?

Answer (score 4):

I'm having exactly this issue and was wondering if you've managed to solve it.
My graphics drivers and display drivers are all fully up to date.
I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit also. 
I've also installed VS2012 and get a similar issue using that IDE.

I've just found this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653315/ui-gets-messed-up
and the work around seems to fix my problem!